# How to set databaseInstanceName in Database Trace Listener from C# code?

Tags: c#, exception, enterprise-library, tracelistener

This might be a simple question. Is there any way by which we can set the databaseInstanceName in Database Trace Listener programitically ? As my application interacts with different databases(lets say in the connectionString tag i have 3 connection strings pointing to different DBs) so I have a requirement to log the exception in db but into respective databases. I am not supoosed to create a separate db for logging.

Is there a way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the fluent API to configure Enterprise Library...

```
var configurationSourceBuilder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();

// do other configuration here

configurationSourceBuilder
    .ConfigureLogging()
        .LogToCategoryNamed("Category")
            .SendTo.Database("Database Trace Listener")
                .UseDatabase("DatabaseInstance");

// or here

var configurationSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
configurationSourceBuilder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configurationSource);
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configurationSource);
```

If the reason you have three connection strings is that your program has to support running in three different environments (dev/test/production?), a better option might be to have a single connection string instead. Then deploy configuration files customized for each environment, so that the code is identical for all environments.

Comment: Hey @Tim B. I added .WithOptions.SetAsDefaultCategory() in the above code and it started working. Thanks a lot :-)